# CSS: Banners squish while I scale down the Browser

Tags: html, css, wordpress, scale

[Here are the full width banners](http://www.gonpires.com/carmacks/) which cause this issue. Im using a Plugin which enables you to upload a certain Image and set it up with a specific ID. So I Uploaded a jpeg with 2000px width and 600px height. Then I assigned the following CSS:

```
 #bannerPages {
 height: 296px;
 margin-top: 183px;
 width: 100%;
```

}

The banners look good on full screen, but they squish while down scaling the browser width. **So I'd like to prevent the squishing effect and cutt the image while down scaling the browser size.** How could I achieve this?

Comment: Also, you should probably get rid of the white space around the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with this for a while, but ultimately came up with two solutions depending on your needs. The first is easier to implement and more accurate to your requirements.

Remove the image from the bannerHome element and add the following code to the CSS.

```
.bannerHome {
    background-image: url('http://www.gonpires.com/carmacks/wp-content/uploads/useful_banner_manager_banners/6-homeJV.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 890px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9sqjs/2/

That method will only work in IE9+, Firefox Chrome, etc. Nice solution if you don't need IE8 support. You'll have to adjust your media queries as well. The other method requires more work and wouldn't crop the sides but it would fit and resize the image inside a 100% width container which would be cross-browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q64S2/1/

Comment: Hi @SacWebDeveloper! You got the idea exactly. Your code works and renders the way I need if I put it on **only one banner**. But It Kills the random rotation effect on the banner's plugin. Is there a way we could implement it on the .bannercustom class, which is the div containing the banners? Actually the plugin allows you to asign a class or ID to each banner, so I have the .bannercustom class, and then a ID for the home banners (#bannerHome) and another one for the pages banner (#bannerPages)

Comment: That wasn't included in your original question, but none the less. Why don't you try using FlexSlider, the jQuery plugin included with your theme? If you aren't interested in a JS slider and want the presumed PHP "random rotation," you could just include the background-image property in-line. <div class="bannerHome" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $random_image_url; ?>')"></div>

Comment: I know comments are not intended just to thank users, but man, you kicked it! Thank u for your help. Have a good one bro!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have a media query that is making the width 140px !important.

Try changing the img on the media query to this

```
 img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 }
```

Comment: I've just tried adding this, and what I see is that the Img keeps its proportions while down scaling, but it does not cut the img, it just lowers it's height and width proportionally. Let's say that I have 10 people standing in a row on a big screen. If I scale down the browser window I only see 9...then 8...and so on. That is what I want to achieve..@Travis

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the image a background image instead?
For the .useful_banner_manager_banner classed div, you can set that large background-image so it'll essentially crop itself based on screen size.